# How to have absolute div fit parent width/padding?

Tags: html, css

I need to have positioning set to absolute so I can have `#bottom` fixed at the bottom of the screen. I also need to have this fit the width/padding of the container `#panel`. When I set the position to absolute however, the width just fills the whole screen's width, how can I stop this? I need #bottom to fit inside the width/padding of `#panel`.

HTML:

```
<div id="panel">
    <div id="bottom">
        <div class="update"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#panel {
    width: 21.25%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #0794ea;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 1.5%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.update {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #006699;
    text-align: center;
    height: 56px;
    color: white;
}

#bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[image]

Above is an image of what's happening. Green is the padding and blue is the content area it should be fitting in (dark blue is the actual div (`#panel`) that I'm trying to fit in the content area). I'm assuming because it's absolute it's ignoring this, I'm looking for a way to get around this.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qTJhW/

Thanks

Comment: Try adding position: relative to #panel.

Comment: That's certainly improved the situation. The #bottom div no longer fills the whole screen, however it is still ignoring #panel's padding (green on the image).

Comment: I am behind the office servers atm. So don't have access to the picture. Can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qTJhW/

Comment: Try adding "left:0px;" to #bottom

Comment: Can you just show me your HTML code?

Comment: @faridv Check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qTJhW/ (also edited question with HTML)

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/qTJhW/1/

Comment: @JeevanJose No, you've removed the padding from #panel. #bottom needs to adapt to the width and the padding, not just the width.

Comment: Is it what you need?
http://jsfiddle.net/9GbfB/

Comment: @adrian.krzysztofek Visually, yes. But you're cheating and using margin :P

Comment: The whole point of making it listen to its parent is to make it more responsive :)

Comment: @JoelKidd I think that the problem is because of the `#panel`'s padding in percents. If you could use pixels for `#panel` like `#panel { padding: 0 20px; }` then you're gonna be able to fit the `#bottom` inside it using `#bottom { margin-left: -20px; }`. I think it's the best workaround. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/faridv/qTJhW/2/)

Comment: @faridv You are correct in that being where the problem is, however that's part of my question, how to do it whilst retaining the percentage. I re-posted a more specific question, answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923153/force-absolute-div-to-listen-to-parents-padding

Comment: @JoelKidd Using percents in CSS doesn't mean that your website is "responsive". In my experience, it's better to write viewport-specific CSS rules for your website. for example padding for `#panel` in **960px** viewport can be `0 20px` and the `#bottom` margin-left is `-20px` while in **1200px** it can be  `0 30px` and `-30px`. Take a look at [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap). I think it has one of the best well-written responsive CSS.

Comment: @faridv You are correct, I meant fluid, my apologies. But yes I do take onboard what you're saying, just in this scenario padding with percentages best suits my situation.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with what you are doing is that it is taking the the entire width including the padding and aligning it to the left side width the padding. You can fix this by using a wrapper with a relative position. Also don't forget to make the #panel position relative.

The code you end up with is something along these lines:

```
<div id="panel">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="bottom">
            <div class="update">
                a          
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#panel {
    width: 21.25%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #0794ea;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 1.5%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.update {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #006699;
    text-align: center;
    height: 56px;
    color: white;
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

#bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: yellow;
}
```

Here is an example:
http://codepen.io/DanielVoogsgerd/pen/Lezjy

Comment: This doesn't quite answer my question due to the structure of the HTML, my fault really. This is what I currently have, if you could modify your answer to suit this I'd appreciate it: http://jsfiddle.net/qTJhW/

Comment: left:0px for #bottom fixes your issue

Comment: Are you able to change the html at all? or does it just need the update inside the bottom div?
Like adrian says you could always just align the box to the left using: `left: 0;`

Comment: Could you recheck the pen? Is this what you mean? http://codepen.io/DanielVoogsgerd/pen/Lezjy

Comment: @DanielVoogsgerd I've posted a new question to help describe my new situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923153/force-absolute-div-to-listen-to-parents-padding

Comment: Updated this question to match the other solution so when people find this post via google there is an answer that solved the problem instead of a link to a different problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc) like this:

```
width: calc(100% - Padding)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should only add **another outer wrapper block with explicitly declare 'position: relative'** then it will work.

In this case:

```
<style>
#outer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>

     <div id="panel">
         <div id="outer">
             <div id="bottom">
                 <div class="update"></div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
```

It will solve your problem.

Answer (score -4):

add left:0px to your absolute id. it start form 0px with his relative id